# How to configure a war in order to depends on the exported libraries in the war instead of the libraries from the server?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I want to deploy a war in a JBoss 4.2 but I don't have control over its dir, so I can't replace the `jsf-impl.jar` and `jsf-api.jar`.

My question is: How to configure the war in order to depends on the `jsf-impl.jar` and `jsf-api.jar` exported in the war instead of this libraries from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the server used. For JBoss 4.2 and newer, you can do that by adding the following context parameter to the webapp's `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: After that I setup my project with the recomended configuration, I realize that my EJBs are not correctly being injected and my references to them are set to null.

But if I remove the libraries within the jar and put this same ones on the jboss server directory runs perfectly.

The problem is I cant do this on the production enviroment, so I need them (the libraries) packed in the war and app references this ones and not the default ones in the server.